# Get count of user stories without any tasks in azure devops analytics api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to write a query against the analytics odata api that returns among other things a count of the number of user stories that have 0 tasks

This is what I have so far

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?
$filter=Project/ProjectId eq {projectId}
    and WorkItemId eq {workItemId}
    and Descendants/any()
  &$select=WorkItemId,WorkItemType,Title,State&
  &$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserName),Iteration($select=IterationPath),Area($select=AreaPath),Links(
                $filter=LinkTypeName eq 'Child';
                $select=LinkTypeName;
                $expand=TargetWorkItem($select=WorkItemType,WorkItemId,Title,State)
            ),
      Descendants(
        $apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'User Story')
        /aggregate($count as CountOfUserStories, StoryPoints with sum as TotalStoryPoints)
      )
```

I'm not sure how to get the count of user stories that have 0 tasks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following syntax to get count of user stories without any children in a team project:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{TeamProject}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?
$apply=
   filter(WorkItemType eq 'User Story')/
   filter(not (Links/any(x:x/LinkTypeName eq 'Child')))/
   aggregate($count as Count)
```

---

Update:

I have tested with the following query, and could get correct count of `CountOfUserStories`, you may have another try:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{TeamProject}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?
$filter=WorkItemId eq {id}
        and Descendants/any()
&$select=WorkItemId,WorkItemType,Title,State&
&$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserName),Iteration($select=IterationPath),Area($select=AreaPath),Links(
                $filter=LinkTypeName eq 'Child';
                $select=LinkTypeName;
                $expand=TargetWorkItem($select=WorkItemType,WorkItemId,Title,State)
            ),
      Descendants(
        $apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'User Story')/
               filter(not (Links/any(x:x/LinkTypeName eq 'Child')))/
               aggregate($count as CountOfUserStories, StoryPoints with sum as TotalStoryPoints)
      )
```

Comment: is there a way to do this as well as use the descendants query because there is some other information I need about descendants of the epics I'm looking at.

Comment: Have you tried add filter `not (Links/any(x:x/LinkTypeName eq 'Child'))` under descendants?

Comment: that doesn't work. Basically I have a list of workitem IDs for epics and I need to get the count per epic of how many user stories have 0 tasks. I also need to be able to get the number per epic of active user stories, number of tasks that have 0 hours, number of stories that have 0 points. I can get all of this information except the number of stories with 0 tasks.

Comment: I can get correct CountOfUserStories using the query I updated in the reply, you may have another try.